# Conditional JS call for IE7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-7

I have a complex site that incorporates alot of javascript and it is getting absolutely KILLED by IE7.  How would I go about serving this code:

HTML

`<div id="curtain" style="display: none"></div>`

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#curtain').delay(1500).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

In such a way that IE7 never gets the `style="display: none"` and therefore never hides `<div id="curtain">`?

Comment: there is something else wrong on your html , the above code should just work in IE7 without any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to set IE7 specific styles.

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<style>
#curtain{ display: block !important;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

But, you should take the display setting out of the `style` attribute, as the level of specificity is high enough that it may override the admittedly hack-y `!important` attribute.

Comment: Good call, however, I'm using inline styles because I NEED that level of specificity for other purposes also, it's important that the div not load and then hide later when that CSS rule is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have a jquery branch which selects on that id and deletes that style attribute when the browser is IE7?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.browser.version can be used to detect ie version

Answer (score 0):

Is space a problem , your code should just work in IE7 without any problem , otherwise there is some problem in your file .

Remove the space , before display : none

```
<div id="curtain" style="display:none"></div>
```